# ¿Por qué "hacer el pino" es poner el cuerpo verticalmente con los pies hacia arriba?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones

El diccionario de la lengua española recoge "[hacer el pino](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T3vyIIP%7CT3wHEqJ)" como:

> Ejercicio gimnástico que consiste en poner el cuerpo verticalmente con los pies hacia arriba, apoyando las manos en el suelo.

desde hace relativamente poco (salvo error, la primera inclusión es en 1989).

La noción de verticalidad viene asociada a "pino" desde ediciones muy anteriores, pero ¿con los pies hacia arriba?

Comment: Aquí usamos "hacer la vertical".

Comment: @Gustavson puede que venga del significado de _pino_ como adjetivo: "muy pendiente o muy derecho". Ahí se dice que _en pino_ significa "en pie, derecho, sin caer". De este adjetivo se genera también "empinado", participio de "empinar" (de _en-_ y _pino_, "derecho").

Answer (score 1):

La expresión hoy día se conoce como "hacer el pino", pero buscando en Ngram he encontrado una entrada en el *Diccionario enciclopédico hispano-americano de literatura, ciencias y artes*, volumen 28 (segundo apéndice, M-Z) de 1910, [que dice así](https://archive.org/stream/diccionarioencic28vizu#page/582/mode/2up):

> HACER EL PINO, o HACER PINOS: Mantenerse en posición vertical, con los pies en alto y la cabeza y las manos apoyadas en el suelo.

El ejemplo que aporta a continuación se puede consultar también [en el CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=100417%5C014%5CC000O10042017142848748.1172.1168&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20hacer%20pinos%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0):

> *Cabalmente el hacer pinos pronto y bien era una de las grandes habilidades de Andrés.*
>
> José María de Pereda, "Sotileza", 1885-1888 (España).

Como ves, antiguamente se decía "hacer pinos", expresión que [se usa también](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T3wHEqJ) para expresar que un niño está dando sus primeros pasos. A eso le tenemos que sumar el hecho de que *pino* es un adjetivo que significa "muy pendiente o muy derecho".

Por tanto, se puede ver el origen de la expresión como que en gimnástica el ejercicio de "hacer el pino" consiste en ponerse muy derecho (solo que con los pies hacia arriba, que si no, no tiene gracia), o incluso que en esa posición uno mantiene la verticalidad a duras penas, tal y como hace un niño que está haciendo pinitos. De hecho, si a una persona en esa posición le dices que intente andar un poco con las manos, andará igual que un bebé que está aprendiendo a caminar.

Mención especial a un artículo de un diario llamado *La Risa*, publicado en Madrid, que tenía una sección de piropos dedicados a las mujeres, enviados por los lectores, y que el 20 de mayo de 1923 [recogía esto](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0025584908&page=4&search=%22hacer%20el%20pino%22&lang=es) en una de esas secciones:

> —So resala: Por una sonrisa dulce de usted, era yo capaz de hacer el *pino* en una de las pirámides de Egipto durante veinticuatro horas, y después atravesarme a nado el Mediterráneo en diez minutos. —UN ATLETA.

En este artículo se aprecia el uso de la expresión actual "hacer el pino" en vez de "hacer pinos".