# Uso y alternativas a 'hacer el pino'

Tags: diferencias-regionales, españa, sinónimos, hispanoamérica

En el libro *Mis geniales predecesores II* escribe el autor

> Me asusté cuando(...) ¡hizo el pino sobre una silla!

Después de algunas consultas, entendí el motivo del susto del autor, al ver que hacer el pino es ponerse de cabeza sobre el suelo (en este caso, sobre una silla) y en [otra pregunta de este sitio](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/por-qu%C3%A9-hacer-el-pino-es-poner-el-cuerpo-verticalmente-con-los-pies-hacia-arr) se menciona acerca del origen de la expresión. Sin embargo, acá en Colombia la gente suele ponerse de cabeza o a un nivel popular 'patas arriba' (creo que no necesita mucha explicación). La expresión 'hacer el pino' ¿Es un españolismo o se usa en otros países? ¿Qué sinónimos se usan en el resto del mundo hispano?

Answer (score 1):

Si no me equivoco, *Mis geniales predecesores* fue escrito por Garry Kasparov, que es de Rusia. Para saber si es un españolismo, habría que saber quién escribió la traducción.

En lo personal, nunca lo había oído. En México se usa la expresion "Parase de cabeza".

Comment: Si es un españolismo, vivo en Barcelona hace 20 años y acá todo el mundo lo dice así incluso en catalán "fer el pi"

Answer (score 1):

En Chile es "hacer la posición invertida"

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar algo más de _chicha_ a la respuesta? Referencias de uso, ejemplos, etc. Si bien estás contestando la pregunta, así queda demasiado justito. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' No se qué quieres que ponga, ejemplos y referencias, me parece que sobran, está súper claro a qué se refiere y cómo se utiliza, adornar por adornar... para qué?